# how to selected/zoom the object without clicking manually

Tags: autodesk-forge, viewer, forge

Please help me on how to selected/zoom the object without clicking manually in forge viewer,

Please provide any link or code, we need to select object when loading itself

Answer (score 1):

The [Viewer3D](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/) class exposes many useful methods such as `getSelection()`, `select(ids)`, or `fitToView(ids)` that can be used for what you need. Most of these methods work with *ids* or *dbids* which are numerical identifiers representing individual objects.

Try opening one of the existing Forge apps (for example https://forge-basic-app.herokuapp.com), open one of the models, select one or more objects in the model, open the browser console, and type in `NOP_VIEWER.getSelection()`. This should return an array of IDs representing the selected objects. Then, try typing `NOP_VIEWER.fitToView(...)` passing in the same array of numbers as the first argument (for example, `NOP_VIEWER.fitToView([123, 456, 789])`). This should bring the selected objects into camera focus.